# cmd.exe escapes two quotes next to each other, even though my first quote is escaped by a caret

Tags: windows-7, command-line, escape-characters

I am having troubles with quotes, I've been at this for hours... I basically have a external program (FOO) and it needs a string to process, and within that string there is a quote in the end and in the beginning.

```
FOO /f "BAR ^"BAZ^""
```

This code is not working because when I escape the quotes containing 'BAZ' it will also escape the last quote because of the fact that two quotes next to each other will be escaped anyway, even if the first quote is escaped by a caret.

I do not want to use something like sed, because I want it to be strictly using Windows Batch.

(**EDIT:** Here is a command which reproduces my problem:

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /t REG_SZ /v Update /d "cmd.exe /c ""echo CreateObject(""Wscript.Shell"").Run """""""" ^& WScript.Arguments(0) ^& """""""", 0, False > invis.vbs && CALL invis.vbs update.bat""" /f
```

)

Comment: Use multiple double-quotes as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/cmd-escape-double-quotes-in-parameter

Comment: @AxelKemper Unfortunately I can't get it to work when using `REG ADD <KEYNAME> /t REG_SZ /v FOO /d "BAR ""BAZ""" /f`. It says incorrect syntax.

Comment: Have you tried a 2 step approach? first write output of cmd.exe ... into an env variable foo and then second using %foo% in the reg command?

Comment: @DavidPostill What do you mean?

Comment: I mean split your long command into two commands

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah, I've tried that, but I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small `C` program to find out what is actually passed from `cmd.exe`

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d: '%s'\n", i, argv[i] ? argv[i] : "<null>");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Call:**

```
consoleapplication1 ADD KEYNAME /t REG_SZ /v FOO /d "BAR ""BAZ""" /f
```

Parameters arrived in the program:

```
0: 'consoleapplication1'

1: 'ADD'

2: 'KEYNAME'

3: '/t'

4: 'REG_SZ'

5: '/v'

6: 'FOO'

7: '/d'

8: 'BAR "BAZ"'

9: '/f'
```

The single quotes are just added for illustration purposes.

**Bottom line:**
The duplicate double-quotes work as expected.

**Note:**
`REG` uses the backslash as special escape character as explained [here](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html).

Comment: Thank you, I tried with my actual command and it gave me a similar result, but for some strange reason, reg add will not be successful using my command specified with `/d`, however when I don't use the inner quotes it does work. Any ideas? (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

Source [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> **Special Cases**
>
> A small number of commands follow slightly different rules, FINDSTR,
>   **REG** and RUNAS all use <kbd>\</kbd> as an escape character instead of <kbd>^</kbd>

You were using:

```
REG ADD <KEYNAME> /t REG_SZ /v FOO /d "BAR ^"BAZ^"" /f
```

Try this instead:

```
REG ADD <KEYNAME> /t REG_SZ /v FOO /d "BAR \"BAZ\"" /f
```

Comment: After A LOT of additional testing, I got this working, thank you!

Comment: Great! It would be useful for any future users who find this question if you could let us know exactly what you did to finally get it to work.

Comment: Well, since I used the REG ADD command and also had a lot of special characters (i.e `&|<>^`) I needed to escape those using a caret, otherwise my particular command would mess up and it would try to append the output of REG ADD to a file if I used the '>' char without escaping it with ^. But it worked when I did escape the special characters with a caret.